# httpd conf environment variables - how do they work? (Centos 6)

Tags: virtualhost, environment-variables, centos6

I have the following config included in my httpd.conf...

```
Include ${MODULE_DIR}/utilities/devconf/bo/vhost.conf
```

where ${MODULE_DIR} is an environment variable that I am setting in my httpd init script (/etc/init.d/httpd) like so:

```
MODULE_DIR=/export/home/modules
```

this line appears before the line that launches httpd.

Now when I attempt to start the Apache server using...

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

I still get the following error:

```
[root@MyCentosVM ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 1011 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf/devconf-vhosts.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/${MODULE_DIR}/utilities/devconf/bo/vhost.conf: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@MyCentosVM ~]#
```

... clearly the environment variable is not being substituted correctly. What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
export MODULE_DIR=/export/home/modules
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I don't think I am. The method I'm using is described in the answer by markdrayton in this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/64656/using-variables-in-apache-config-files-to-reduce-duplication

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I just found the answer and came back to post it but found that you beat me to it :) Thanks